# How to change an input() to lower case?

Tags: python-3.x

I'm new to python and trying my best to learn. At this moment I'm following to program along with YouTube. But I got stuck with this piece of code where I'm trying to change user input to lowercase and comparing it to a list to see if item is available or not. And ever time I ran code I get Not available. Here is the code:

```
stock = ['Keyboard', 'Mouse', 'Headphones', 'Monitor'] 

productName = input('Which product would you like to look up:').lower()

if productName in stock
   print('Available') 
else:
    print('Not Available') 

 - List item
```

Comment: Your code *does* convert the input to lower case. The problem is that the strings in your list are not lower case. Either you need to edit the strings in your list so they are lower case, or you need to use `.capitalize()` instead of `.lower()`.

Comment: I believe python string equality testing is case sensitive so if you are storing a lower case string in the productName variable then this would not match any of the list element in stock which all begin with an uppercase letter. Perhaps changing the first letter of the user input to uppercase before membership testing may help ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your `stock` array to be all lowercase, like so:

```
stock = ['keyboard', 'mouse', 'headphones', 'monitor']
```

Because you modify the user input to be lowercase, no matter what, and the stock items in the array are capitalized, no matter what, they will never match in your `if` statement. String comparison in Python is case sensitive (as it is in nearly every programming language).